# Binary Exponentiation is not working properly when the base is a float/double

Tags: c++, exponentiation

I learned how to implement binary exponentiation in c++ from [this](https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/binary-exp.html#toc-tgt-1) site. I used the recursive algorithm:

```
long long binpow(long long a, long long b) {
    if (b == 0)
        return 1;
    long long res = binpow(a, b / 2);
    if (b % 2)
        return res * res * a;
    else
        return res * res;
}
```

In my situation, I need `a` to be a double value. I did this to do that:

```
double binpow(double a, long long b) {
    if (b == 0)
        return 1;
    long long res = binpow(a, b / 2);
    if (b % 2)
        return res * res * a;
    else
        return res * res;
}
```

I do not need `b` to be a double, and I know that if `b` were a double, I would need to use a different approach to get the real value.

When I ran the code with: `binpow(3.1, 3)`, the correct answer would be `29.79`, but the binpow algorithm gave me `27.9`. I also tried `binpow(9.23, 3)`, and it gave me `747.63`, while the real answer was `786.33`.

Also, when i switch to the naive method:

```
double naive(double a, long long b) {
    
    double final = 1;
    
    for (;b > 0; b--) {
        final*=a;
    }
    
    return final;
}
```

I get the correct answer of `786.33`

What is the issue here, and is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Change input parameter b to double instead of long long as well? There is probably implicit casting going on. double binpow(double a, double b). Or explicitly cast inside the function where needed. Also your long long is returned, while ur function return is double

Comment: @OmidCompSCI that's not necessary. Is good to have integer exponent... because the algorithm only works that way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are converting the result of `binpow` to a `long long` here:

```
long long res = binpow(a, b / 2);
```

which changes the result.

Instead, you need to do:

```
double res = binpow(a, b / 2);
```

or even better

```
auto res = binpow(a, b / 2);  // so res has the same type that binpow returns
```

which fixes the issue. Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xi-8na).